Why am I getting this error "Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part" when writing an Excel file with openpyxl?
I am very new to Python and getting an error that I can't seem to resolve. In my Python script I am querying a Snowflake database and then turning the results into a dataFrame (df). Following this, I simply write an .xlsx file.
This all works fine until I open the Excel file. I'm greeted by a message "We found a problem with some content in the ‘file.XLSX’. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?" Upon clicking "yes" the file contains all of the data in a repaired version of the file. The log of repairs is as follows "Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part"
I've tried to leverage a number of solutions with no luck. I experimented with using xlwings and cleaning my columns to strip any potential leading "=". Again, I'm new to Python so I don't really know where to go from here.
import os
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#SQL Code - Removed for Privacy

# Execute the query
cursor_clm_dm = conn_clm_dm.cursor()
cursor_clm_dm.execute(query)

# Fetch the results
results = cursor_clm_dm.fetchall()

# Convert the results to a Pandas DataFrame
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor_clm_dm.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=columns)

# Close the cursor and connection
cursor_clm_dm.close()
conn_clm_dm.close()
conn_clm_dw.close()

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

df.to_excel('C:\\Users\\JohnG\\Downloads\\file.xlsx', index=False)
print('done')


Well what you have in your code is a bog standard write a dataframe to Excel using Pandas to_excel which is used and known to work by thousands. We/you assume that the issue is with the data you are writing an since that's not included there isn't much people can comment. You need to provide a [mre] including a dataframe (DF) of the same data you are writing. Likely the [mre] does not need to include any part of the data retrieval from the Database (at this stage anyway). Surely you can provide some of the data you are writing as a DF in the code (anonymised if necessary).

I think Pandas doesn't use Openpyxl by default when dumping to a workbook, so that probably won't help with the problem. Either that, or the supplied code is incomplete and you're using an existing workbook.
